# What are ways to train ones lasthitting skills

Tags: league-of-legends

So I'm a high elo player and I only play Support since I can't really keep up with the farm in High elo. While I have 160 - 180 CS on average in 20 minutes my opponents are at around 180-220 and this is just a huge gold advantage which is pretty fatal in my elo.

Now I've already tried farming in custom games, but this isn't really the same. I have no trouble Hitting 240 (Max) creeps in 20 minutes but when it comes to real games I rapidly fall behind because of harrass, ganks or creep deny in general.

What ways are there to improve at farming even more? I'm just really bored of playing support all day but I can't really keep up with diamond farm so I somehow have to improve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I highly recommend you sticking to one role and becoming an expert in it instead of mastering different roles. But for the sake of the question;

10 min farming training:

- CS farming sessions should be 10 minutes. (Actually 8 is the perfect number, but for calculation ease we used 10)
- You should not have any runes or masteries when you are practicing last hitting and you should not power up skills. This will greatly help your early game last hitting with non-ad champions and improve your lane freezing skills.
- You need to train everyday before playing and train with each champion you play.
- Find a buddy who will also follow this training

After you guys really master this training with every champion, you are ready to do the same training with an added element: Harassing

- 2 champions in one lane you have to last hit like before .
- When your opponent gets a cs, you can hit them only once, 0-1 second after they get a minion kill.

This will improve your harassing ability, you will feel more comfortable about when you have to harass and when you will get harassed after you master this training.

Mastering this training guarantees Diamond1 in any lane except jungle and support.

Comment: In order to raise the difficulty of this exercice, try to do this with a mage champion with a slow, not very powerful autoattack, like Soraka or Vladimir

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, begin playing jungle and still not worry about last hitting :)

Or the hard way... play champions a lot and get used to them.  Each champion is different.  Also, some champions you can run flat AD marks which can make last hitting easier too.  Sometimes running those ad marks means the difference when you are farming off a turret, if you only need 1 hit to kill a minion after a turret hit or 2.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** I've just started my first ranked season last week. I don't drill or anything, I'm just playing ranked for some extra fun. I also play Support primarily, and do quite well given a capable team. (And if my team sucks, you'll never hear me complain, I just do what I can - as is the fate of support, we go in together or we go down together...)

**Anyway - on to training!** If I was going to train for high elo this is what I would do:

**Set up your training environment:**
Your environment needs to be controlled so you can train for the things you are interested in, but also as similar to live play as possible. Use Custom game mode, but bring some friends willing to train with you.

**Find partner(s):**
Find a partner (ideally in your case three-partners) to drill with you in custom games. The goal is to face off in the same lane, in the same roles, with different champion combinations to simulate a real game in a controlled environment.

**What to train (this can be done in custom 1v1 or 2v2 with bots filling the rest):**

- Farming
- Positioning vs other champs
- Harass (counter harass)
- Builds
- Engages
- Escapes
- Ganks
- Turret Diving etc...

**Don't train it all at once:**
Pick a couple topics and drill one or two of them often (daily).
Once a week, run a full game with your 1v1 or 2v2 group (at least until it's obvious which side is "winning") to put all the drilling into more practical use.

Like Esq mentioned when you train a topic, set up your training so that you have to rely on only that to gain your advantage. So if you are training farming - don't upgrade skills, just work on Last Hits with a timer, and work out how you did at the end of the session.

**Identified a Weakness?:**
If you find a particular nasty gap in your play, focus on it! Say you like to play Cait and seem to always lose ground against Sivir (a common thing in Bronze) - play Cait, get one of your buddies to play Sivir and face off to work on it.

**Retrospective / planning:**
After the weekly game, talk about what went well, what went poorly and identify training goals for the next week.

Comment: I will bet that you are a consultant ! :-D